# For all k < n such that gcd(k, n)=1 , k has finite order

Tags: number-theory

I am on my way to understanding Euler's theorem. I am reading Mathematics for CS by Tom Leighton.

Let $gcd1(n)$ be the set of integers in [1,n), that are relatively prime to n.

Define the order of k over $Z_n$ to be: $m=ord(k,n)$ = the least power of k such that $k^m=1$

**Every element of $gcd1(n)$ has finite order**

The proof is given in the textbook.

Proof:

Suppose $k \in gcd1(n)$ We need to show is that some power of k over $Z_n$
equals 1.
But since $gcd1(n)$ has fewer than n elements, some number must occur twice in
the list

$k^1, k^2, ... k^n$

That is

$k^ik^m=k^i$

for some m > 0 and $i \in [0,n)$. But k is cancellable over $Z_n$
, so we can cancel the
first i of the k’s on both sides to get

$k^m=1$

Proof complete.

The part $k^ik^m=k^i$ is not obvious to me. Why for some i > j, $k^i = k^j$ in $Z_n$

Comment: Write it as $k^i = k^j$ for some $i\ne j$, WLOG assume $j>i$ then write $j=m+i$ so $k^j = k^{m+i} = k^m k^i$

Comment: @AlexR I updated my question. What I dont understand is Why for some i > j, $k^i=k^j$

Comment: By the pigeonhole principle, where the holes are $\gcd_1(n)$ (if $\gcd(k,n) = 1$ so is $\gcd(k^i \bmod n, n) = 1$ for any $i$.

Comment: @AlexR Thanks. It's gotten clear now. If you post the answer, I'll accept it. But I think it should be "$gcd(k^i mod n, n) = 1 for some i, but not for any i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the pigeonhole principle, where the holes are $\gcd_1(n)$ (if $\gcd(k,n) = 1$ so is $\gcd(k^i \bmod n, n) = 1$ for any $i$.) we get that for some $i\ne j\in [0, n]$, $k^i=k^j$. Now assume WLOG $j>i$ and write $j=m+i$ for some $m>0$ to obtain
$$k^i = k^j = k^{m+i} = k^m k^i$$
as desired.